# If statement = crashes my App

Tags: if-statement, button, netbeans, codenameone

I am creating an App and it crashes when I click the button to increase the value in a text field by 1. This is a button click event.

I have placed everything in a while loop that will never end. Then the ifs will increase the value by 1 in the int and then store it into a string that will set the value to the text box. I will also be including a decrease button to do the reverse.

```
 String SetUp = findTxtComp().getText();

int ChstSetLoop;
ChstSetLoop = 1;

        while(ChstSetLoop == 1){
            ChstSetLoop = 1;
    if(SetUp.equals("0")){


        SetUp = "1";

        findTxtComp().setText("1");
        ChstSetLoop = 0;
    }
    else if(SetUp.equals("1")){


        SetUp = "2";

        findTxtComp().setText(SetUp);
        ChstSetLoop = 0;
    }
    else if(SetUp.equals("2")){


        SetUp = "3";

        findTxtComp().setText(SetUp);
        ChstSetLoop = 0;
    }
    else if(SetUp.equals("3")){


        SetUp = "4";

        findTxtComp().setText(SetUp);
        ChstSetLoop = 0;
    }
    else if(SetUp.equals("4")){


        SetUp = "5";

        findTxtComp().setText(SetUp);
        ChstSetLoop = 0;

    }

    else{

        SetUp = "0";

    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe want to include the error?  What does `findTxtComp()` do?

Comment: You never change the value of `ChstSetLoop `, so of course your loop will never end. And most of the rest of the code is utterly pointless. `foo = 4; foo = String.valueOf(foo)`? Why just just `foo = "4"`?

Comment: findTxtComp() will find the text box named txtcomp. I am using Codename one. The button is supposed to increase the number in the text box by 1 each time it is pressed. There are two variables SetUP which is integer and SetUp which is String.

Comment: I figured it out. See code thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Placing things in an infinite loop is a big mistake. Besides draining the battery it will actually not work.

If the loop is on the EDT then you will effectively block all event processing and drawing thus breaking your app: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/callserially-the-edt-invokeandblock-part-1.html

If the loop is in a separate thread you will be violating the EDT by accessing it on a separate thread.

For handling these things we have event callbacks (e.g. action event for button click) see http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code